# Python equivalent for Ruby's ObjectSpace?

Tags: python, ruby, module, metaprogramming

I've a name of a class stored in var, which I need to create an object from.
However I do not know in which module it is defined (if I did, I would just call getattr(module,var), but I do know it's imported.

Should I go over every module and test if the class is defined there ? How do I do it in python ?

What if I have the module + class in the same var, how can I create an object from it ? (ie var = 'module.class')
Cheers,
Ze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`globals()[classname]` should do it.

More code: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/285262/

Answer (score 0):

Classes are not added to a global registry in Python by default. You'll need to iterate over all imported modules and look for it.

Comment: When I run `globals()` I see a little more than nothing. Am I special?

Comment: @Oli: You *do* know that `globals()` only shows you the names in the *current* module... right?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing the classname as a string, why don't you store the class object in the var, so you can instantiate it directly.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print 'A new object created'
... 
>>> class_object = A
>>> object = class_object()
A new object created
>>>
```